# Text to tex converter

Tags: conversion, convert

I remember using some sites where I could make some screenshots and convert it into tex code but I can't find it anymore. I would appreciate any help and recommendations!

Comment: Your title says "text" to "tex" converter, but screenshots are typically images; are you trying to convert some text, or some kind of diagram, or math, or ... ?

Comment: Like mathpix (I have never used it.)?

Comment: https://mathpix.com/

Comment: Thanks! I have a pdf ihr of which I would like to take some screenshots